# root and home are on separate partitions, but home still uses up space on root?

Tags: files, root, home-directory

When installing Ubuntu 12.10 for the first time, I made sure /home had it's own partition, gave it about 185GB, and gave root ~10GB.
Now root is almost full after a few days and I've noticed that root is as big as /home and some additional MB from some actual root files.
Note that I deleted some unused files in /home to make sure it really affects how much space is used in root, and it clearly does. (checked in gparted)
I've also made sure the files I am talking about are actually in /home/myname/ and not just in root's home.

df -h spits out this information:

```
df: `/root/.gvfs': Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdb2       9.2G  7.9G  908M  90% /
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  932K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  6.4M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M  112K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb3       184G  4.9G  170G   3% /home
/dev/sdb4       729G   87G  642G  12% /media/mave/Storage
```

I cut out my windows partitions as I don't see any relevance.

I hope this is enough information for someone to tell me what I did wrong

Here another call of df -h after deleting some more files:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       9.2G  7.7G  1.1G  88% /
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  932K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  6.2M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M  100K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb3       184G  4.9G  170G   3% /home
/dev/sdb4       729G   87G  642G  12% /media/mave/Storage
```

Comment: Can you give the output of this command? `sudo du -sh /*; sudo du -sh /root/*`

Comment: Or if you could post the results of your `df -h` test before and after deleting files under `~/` as you describe?

Comment: @medigeek
`8.9M /bin`
`29M /boot`
`4.0K /cdrom`
`12K /dev`
`14M /etc`
`4.7G /home`
`0 /initrd.img`
`0 /initrd.img.old`
`223M /lib`
`3.4M /lib32`
`4.0K /lib64`
`16K /lost+found`

Comment: @TimBooth
edited the main question.

Comment: `df -h ~/` ? (To see the info about the partition your home directory is actually on.)

Comment: Well one does need to be able to compare root and home, though. Thanks for the tip, anyway!

Comment: hmm... run `find ~/ -lname '/*'` to get a list of all symlinks in your home directory, which point to the root. There might be a directory link, causing directory content to be stored on your root partition.

Comment: I'm seeing quit a list of /.wine/ links.
Might it be a bad steam install on wine?

Comment: Thanks @Void - could you tell us exactly what files you deleted, and from where? Under `~/` as you said before? Symlinks seems the most probable cause at this stage.

Comment: I moved a folder from /home/mave/Dropbox/ to another partition (Storage) as I didn't have any unnecessary files to be deleted.

Comment: Sorry to ask you to keep deleting your stuff for diagnostic purposes! Do you use any windows programs via wine on your dropbox files?

Comment: Nope, wine didn't touch any files in dropbox or vice versa.
Overview on the links http://pastebin.com/5MH4RZPT

Answer (score 1):

Your root partition is probably filling up with the package cache from system updates. Run `sudo apt-get clean` to remove package files which where already installed. Apt normally keeps package files after downloading, even though they are already unzipped and installed and have nothing to do with the function of the software anymore.

Apart from that 10 Gig are a little cozy for a contemporary Ubuntu.

Comment: I've already done that after seeing this being suggested in some forums but it only cleared a few MB, which wasn't so surprising considering the fact I have only just started using Ubuntu.
And I've also tried resizing partitions, which was also very problematic. Doesn't belong here right now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output in your question, I see a change in `/dev/sdb2` but not a change in `/dev/sdb3`. This leads me to believe that the files you deleted were on `/dev/sdb2`. If they were in fact under `~/` then that means, transitively, that `~/` is on `/dev/sdb2`. We can confirm or deny this by running the following:

```
sudo mount
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=18812k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=37624k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=37624k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

And you will be looking for a line that looks like

```
/dev/sdb3 on /home type ext3 (rw,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

If you don't see a line like that try to run this:

```
ls -l /home ## Do not put a trailing slash here (i.e., not "/home/" )
```

If you see something like...

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 9 Oct 28 19:48 ./link -> ./some/other/path
```

... then `/home` is still on your root partition.

Comment: I can see the line
`/dev/sdb3 on /home type ext4 (rw)`

Comment: Hmm, try to `ls -l /home/*` and see if anything there symlinks back to `/dev/sdb2`. If not then it is merely a coincidence that `/dev/sdb2` changed in size before.

Comment: No symlinks here. http://pastebin.com/UYfh8DTp
I still wonder how my root is so large though.
I guess I'll look into wine tomorrow, maybe it really is just that.

Comment: `du` is more useful for finding out which folders contain more information. `du -s -h ./*` will summarize each folder and file in the current directory.